# Why typedef throws declaration error in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, typedef

```cpp
//nothing above
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QCheckBox>

typedef QList<QList<QComboBox*>*> ComboLists;
```

typedef is used right after #include area so it cannot be connected with other ';' token errors

this leads to declaration error with ';'

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\XML_TV\xmlmessage.h:18: error: invalid declarator before ';' token
In file included from ..\XML_TV\widget.h:8,
                 from ..\XML_TV\widget.cpp:1:
..\XML_TV\xmlmessage.h:18:45: error: invalid declarator before ';' token
   18 | typedef QList<QList<QComboBox*>*> ComboLists;
    |                                             ^
```

Cleaning project doesn't helping at all. One day before this error everything worked perfectly.

Comment: As usual, what did you change? Also, extract a [mcve], please! Note that this error could be cause by something before the line it occurs in.

Comment: Yeah. I know about that something before the lines can cause an error. But it only have #include and #define areas. Nothing more. To reproduce this example is only required  to write `typedef some_type some_name` . That is the only thing that causes an error. I assume that there is something with modules, compiler or .moc files. I don't know

Comment: These areas you mention are just a convention, they are regular code. So, yes, you can and should reduce their content for a [mcve].

Comment: It may seem stupid, but try to put a few spaces in. `typedef QList<QList<QComboBox *> *> ComboLists;` and see if that helps.

I've seen such errors which resulted from template types being strung together, though that was with something like `typedef QList<QList<QComboBox *>> ComboLists;` (Note that `>>` is the stream operator)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do two typedefs and nest those.
`typedef QList<QComboBox*> ComboList; typedef QList<ComboList *> ComboLists;`

Comment: I tried nesting and adding spaces between gt signs and unfortunately it didn't help. There is the same error. I'll try to create a new project and see how it will work with it.

Comment: This works great with a new project. I think this is most likely related to the .moc files. I think I need to try fixing this manually.

Comment: It didn't help :)

Comment: The issue is probably in widget.h or in the other files included from it